# Applying Query Results to PHP / jQuery Newsfeed

Tags: php, jquery

I have a news feed that is being used for a ticketing information system. The effects of the news feed is identical to Facebook's news feed and will fetch data only when there is new content to be fetched.

I have an issue with understanding where to apply a SQL query result to a multidimensional array that will be used in a JSON function to return the additional content to be added to the news feed. Here is the code below:

feed.php

```
<? php
    $array_with_news = array(
        'news1' => array('pk' => 'pk1', 'title' => 'title1', 'content' => 'title2'), 
        'news2' => array('pk' => 'pk2', 'title' => 'title2', 'content' => 'content2')
    );
    echo json_encode($array_with_news);
?>
```

main.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text\javascript">
            window.setInterval(function() {
                updateNews();
            }, 5000);


            function updateNews() {
                var scope = this;
                $.getJSON('newsFeed.php*', function(data) {
                    //data will contain the news information
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        this.addNewsRow(value);
                    });
                });
            }

            function addNewsRow(newsData) { 
                //this function will add html content 
                var pk = newsData.pk, title = newsData.title, content = newsData.content;
                $('#news').append(pk + ' ' + title + ' ' + content);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="news"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The table containing feed information will be like this

> pk, title, category, content

Also, I only want to fetch new data if it needs to be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to know how to get the SQL result in to your JSON array and, #2, you want to only grab updates. Here's my take on it

feed.php

```
// store the last updated time in the db, get it here
$last_update = $user->get_last_update();

// obviously, this probably has a lot more logic
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE post_time > $last_update";
$news = array();

while($row = query($sql))
{
    $key = 'news'.count($news);
    $news[$key] = array(
        'pk' => $row->pk, 
        'title' => $row->title, 
        'content' => $row->content
   );
}

echo json_encode($news);

query('UPDATE users SET last_update_time=now()');
```

Take this more as psuedo-code - to see how your code should flow. If I misunderstood the question then I will revise my answer.